# How to Identify Items in an Array That Have Moved Relative Position

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, position

**Rewriting this whole question with way more context/information**

Let's say there are objects somewhere representing fruit and each have an ID and a price.

> 1 - Banana - $1

> 2 - Apple - $2

> 3 - Orange - $3

> 4 - Pear - $4

> 5 - Pineapple - $5

The ID's of the items are stored in order of the last updated (newest to oldest) in Array A

```
arrA = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

That is, item 1 is the newest updated item and item 5 is the oldest updated item. Let's say I update the price for the Apple and the Orange. I add 50c to both.

Now the array becomes:

```
arrB = [3,2,1,4,5]
```

That is, Orange (ID 3) is the latest update, Apple (ID 2) is the next latest and then 1,4,5 remain in the same order because they haven't been updated.

I simply want to identify which of the ID's have moved (i.e. were updated) using just the order of the two Arrays if that is even at all possible and store it in Array C

So in this case, Array C should contain 3 and 2. The length of the arrays may change, but the values should be the same across both arrays.

I've considered using the python Zip function to try and compare the two arrays e.g.

```
def moved(arrA, arrB):
    moved = []

    for a, b in zip(arrA, arrB):
        if a != b:
            moved.append(b)

    return moved

arrA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arrB = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

moved_values = moved(arrA, arrB)

print("Moved values:", moved_values)
```

However this fails because it doesn't take into account the fact that 1 originally appeared before 2 in Array A. It simply sees that 2 and 2 are in the same position between both Arrays and has therefore not moved, which is incorrect. Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: 'Relative' to what?  I don't think you've made it clear what the rules are here.  Why does 3 moving in front of 1 count as 'moving' but 1 moving behind 3 not count as moving?

Comment: I don't think the problem is well formed. Each element except the first and last has a "relative position" to _two_ other elements. You say that `1`,`4`,`5` should be considered unmoved, but it seems to me that `1` and `4` have definitely moved relative position: `1` now has different elements before and after it, and `4` has a different element in front of it. Or if you meant their index position then `4`,`5 `have not moved but `1` has.

Comment: If the values are the same, how can the lengths differ?

Comment: i.e. it may not always be 5 items in the array, it may be 10 or 100, but the values will always be the same across both arrays, just potentially in a different order. I'm sorry I am just bad at forming the question. I have updated to try and be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A and B differ, you must've updated something. The latest update is B[0], so remove it from both and add it to C.

If A and B are equal, it's impossible to tell whether anything was updated. Your example shows that you then assume nothing was.

```py
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = [3,2,1,4,5]

C = []
while A != B:
    latest = B.pop(0)
    A.remove(latest)
    C.append(latest)

print(C)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY36x0VbBWiDXWMdIx1THRMY7mcQHxjIN8QwudyBgnEcpVnZOakKjgqKNoqOFlxKQBBTmJJanEJUNZJryC_QMNAEyzqqFeUmptflqoBkYYIOuslFhSk5qXABbkKijLzSjScNSHOgLoG5ioA)):

```
[3, 2]
```

Answer (score -2):

not really sure what this means but this code should identify which items have changed position in the list

```
arrA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arrB = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

moved = []

for i in arrB:
    if (i in arrA) and (arrB.index(i) != arrA.index(i)):
        moved.append(i)

print(moved)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).